# Explicitly change a knockout observable value

Tags: knockout.js

I want to explicitly change a knockout observable. I tried doing something like this but what happened was the integer was written to the variable and the observable was over written:

```
self.test = ko.observable(); 

var array = [1,3,4]; 

self.test = array.length; //self.test is no longer an observable, is now an int with value of 3
```

I tried doing something like this too:

```
self.numOfAsstsInUpdateGrid() = self.dynamicData.length;
```

But I get an "Invalid left-hand side in assignment" error

Comment: self.numOfAsstsInUpdateGrid(self.dynamicData.length); do like this. observable is like function it is not a property.

Comment: Observable is a function :) not like a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.test(array.length);
```

This will preserve test as an observable and set it equal to array.length. Whenever you're setting the value of an observable, you pass the desired value in the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using an array I'd recommend using ko.observableArray. Which has some nice helper functions like remove. Changing the value of observable can be done by passing a value into the observable function. Like so

self.test = ko.observable();

self.test([1,3,4]);

Calling the function will return the value.

var length = self.test().length;

Comment: Wait, Passing in an array into an observable implicitly converts it to an observable array?

Comment: nope thats my fault my example is confusing. The reason this works is because the observable will return whatever you store inside of it. It returns the array which has a length property. Read this, 
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html